# I am working on highcharts, and want to adjust tooltip with chart name ( chart title )

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Please go through the link, When I mouse over into chart, it should display tooltip with chart title(Chart name).

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/c7L7huf4/1/)

```js
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: [
        'Jan',
        'Feb',
        'Mar',
        'Apr'

      ],
      crosshair: true
    },
    yAxis: {
      min: 0,
      title: {
        text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
      }
      /* headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
       footerFormat: '</table>',
       shared: true,
       useHTML: true*/
    },
    plotOptions: {
      column: {
        pointPadding: 0.2,
        borderWidth: 0
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Tokyo',
      data: [49.9]

    }, {
      name: 'New York',
      data: [83.6]

    }, {
      name: 'London',
      data: [48.9]

    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 200px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: You can edit header http://jsfiddle.net/c7L7huf4/2/ or use [tooltip formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter) for customisation.

Comment: I invite you to put your comment in form of an answer, I think it is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that when you say "chart" you mean the container and not the series.

[Tooltip](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/tooltip) field works only on series:

> The tooltip appears when hovering over a point in a series. By default the tooltip shows the values of the point and the name of the series.

You can however make a tooltip appear when the user hovers over the entire chart with the title HTML attribute as in this fiddle:

```
<div title="Monthly Average Rainfall" id="container" style="min-width: 200px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c7L7huf4/1/

Hope it helps.

Comment: In the Highcharts there is not something like  tooltip: {
           title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
        }.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit header http://jsfiddle.net/c7L7huf4/2 or use [tooltip formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter) for customisation.

```
tooltip:{
        headerFormat: '<span>Monthly Average Rainfall</span><br><span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true
    },
```